# Is there a way to attach x86dbg with ida pro?

Tags: ida, debugging

IDA has the option to use debuggers but the debuggers are quite limited. Is there a way that I can use to use x86dbg with IDA Pro?

Comment: have u seen this tutorial? https://disassemble.blog/2018/07/13/debugging-a-dll-in-x64dbg-and-sync-with-ida/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [x64dbgida](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbgida), this is a plugin for IDA Pro.